# How do I allow my app to scroll left right and down to another page without buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Similar to what we see with the Snapchat application.

This is the code I've been working with from multiple videos I've looked at on Youtube.

I find this error at the end the last line of code.

Currently, It's stating expected expression.

Thanks for your input!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var navigationController: UINavigationController {

    weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0", bundle: nil)

        self.addChildViewController(vc0)
        scrollView.addSubview(vc0.view)
        vc0.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


        let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)

        var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
        frame1.origin.x = vc1.view.frame.size.width
        vc1.view.frame = frame1

        self.addChildViewController(vc1)
        scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
        vc1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)



        let vc2 = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil)

        let frame2 = vc2.view.frame
        frame1.origin.x = vc2.view.frame.size.width
        vc2.view.frame = frame2

        self.addChildViewController(vc2)
        scrollView.addSubview(vc2.view)
        vc2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)



        let vc3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil)

        var frame3 = vc3.view.frame
        frame3.origin.x = vc3.view.frame.size.width
        vc3.view.frame = frame3

        self.addChildViewController(vc3)
        scrollView.addSubview(vc3.view)
        vc3.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake.self.view.frame.size.width * 4, self.view.frame.size.height - 66)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: I believe is there is a navigation class for this when you create a new activity. Other than that I think you can accomplish this by listening to user gestures on the screen and launching new activities via `intents` after a gesture is recognized

Comment: Can you explain I've tried adding that nav class at the top. Intents, explain?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  What are you trying to say the last "scrollView.contentSize = ..." line?  Put your example up on github if you can.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAlg5BnYUU I'm trying to do swipe navigation rather than buttons based off this video and I seem to be doing something wrong with that last line, do further explain?

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? @Mr.Classy